# How to Know Result of System.Window.Forms.Help.ShowHelp

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Does anyone know how to capture the result of the call to `System.Window.Forms.Help.ShowHelp`, for example, whether or not it finds the file, and the file is of correct format, and the launching of the window succeeds.

From the documentation of Microsoft at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.help.aspx), apparently it does not return anything, nor throw any exception!

Comment: I removed visual-studio-2010 tag since it doesn't related to the question.

Answer (score 1):

No, apperently where is not way to get the result of this method in some "standard" way. You need to verify existence of the file/link before calling this method manually. It will throw `ArgumentException` only on `null` input.